# VB.Net Databinding if Access is not installed on the client machine?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

I have a database system that I use for work which is self developed. I use an Ms Access database to collect the information from the form. The application works fine and I have no issues with it.

My company is taking my desktop PC away from me and replacing it with a laptop, however they've pre-warned that office will not be available on this laptop as we can hot desk if office applications are required.

The question is, will my application still be able to databind to the Ms Office (.accdb) database and write via SQL, even though office is not installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VB.NET application can manipulate Access .accdb database files without having the Microsoft Access or Microsoft Office applications installed. You *do* need to have the Access Database Engine installed, which is available as a free download here:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)